# External variable not updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, external

i'm trying to set the value of a boolean. I can set it successfully, however, in another class, the changes reflected don't show up.

Here's an example:

File1:

```
@implementation ClassOne //UIViewController

extern BOOL theValue;

- (void)loadFile {
    theValue = YES;
}
...
@end
```

File2:

```
@implementation ClassTwo //UIViewController
BOOL theValue;
- (void)switchValueChanged {
    theValue = NO;
}


@end
```

I initally set the value in class one, with the initial value of YES. However, when I set the value in ClassTwo to equal NO and return back to ClassOne, the value is still YES.

I'm a little bit stuck. You would think it would update. But it doesn't.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe show some more code and where it is exactly located, i.e. what methods etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When my app launches, it sets theValue to YES by default. Problem was that I was using a `viewWillAppear:animated` method for this and every time the ClassTwo's view was dismissed the `viewWillAppear:animated` method was called and the value that *was set* had been reset. I changed the method to `viewDidLoad` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to accomplish what you are after is to declare the BOOL in your appDelegate's interface file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : ....
{
  BOOL theValue;
}

@property BOOL theValue;
```

Then from ClassOne or ClassTwo you can get/set the variable directly by:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate * )[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.theValue = YES;
```

OR

If you really want to access it **globally**, simply declare the variable **outside** your `@interface ... @end` block

```
BOOL theValue
@interface AppDelegate : ... 
{ 
...
}
```

And then you can access the variable `theValue` from anywhere in your code by simply importing the AppDelegate header file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation ClassOne : ....
...
theValue = YES;
```

Comment: He already uses extern for a global variable... at least that's what the code suggests.

Comment: @Eiko you're right, I missed that bit. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "not working"? Error messages? Same result as above? Maybe update your question with the new code you are using.

Comment: The first time I tried the app delegate method, and accessing the variable through appDelegate.theValue;. When I went to check the log, I saw that the value wasn't updated. I then tried the method by putting the variable outside of the @interface block, and that didn't work, the value staying as YES.

Comment: I just tried both and they work fine. Here's a simple example that you can download http://bit.ly/g6dpSv. I log the variable values on the console for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're be better off using the Singleton Design Pattern... http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/